# How does php arrow function work exactly with print function?

Tags: php

we know that print function always return 1, so when using it like this:

```
$arr = [10, 20, 30, 40];
$arr2 = array_map(fn ($num) => print $num, $arr);
```

The output will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
```

because the returned value will be assigned to array elements,
but when I use it like this:

```
$var = fn ($name, $age) => print "Hello my name is $name and I'm $age years old";
$var("Ahmad", 22);
```

The output will be:

```
//Output: Hello my name is Ahmad and I'm 22 years old
```

shouldn't the output here be 1?

Comment: The output of your first example is: 10203040. The output you claim to get is for print_r($arr2).

Comment: Just `echo` then. See https://3v4l.org/cmTmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is still `1`.

If you dump the value you will get `1`:

```
var_dump($var("Ahmad", 22));
//Return int(1)
```

However the result of your arrow function is not used and you just print a message. That's the reason why you think the value of print is different.